# Detect numeric vector elements that are within a certain distance from another element

Tags: r

I have a `test_vector` of numbers and I would like to flag the location in vector of any number that is within say 20 of another element. Any idea how to flag in the example below.

14550 (location 1) and 14554 (location 6)?

```
test_vector <- c(14550, 16072, 15099, 19434, 21040, 14554)
```

Comment: Should the vector keep this sequence, or can it be sorted?

Comment: Need to keep it in order but if it could be sorted and then used to find the location, that would work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg already posted a solution that doesn't require any sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `outer`

```
x[rowSums(abs(outer(x, x, `-`)) < 20) > 1]
## [1] 14550 14554
```

Or if want the locations

```
which(rowSums(abs(outer(x, x, `-`)) < 20) > 1)
## [1] 1 6
```

---

Some benchmarks against the proposed alternatives

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1e6, 1e3)
microbenchmark(Outer = which(rowSums(abs(outer(x, x, `-`)) < 20) > 1),
               Sapply = which(rowSums(abs(sapply(x, `-`, x)) < 20) > 1),
               Vapply = which(rowSums(abs(vapply(x, `-`, x, FUN.VALUE = double(length(x)))) < 20) > 1),
               Dist = which(rowSums(as.matrix(dist(x)) < 20) > 1))

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   Outer 16.43502 17.84158 30.22553  18.99517  58.39895  64.28932   100 a  
#  Sapply 24.66530 26.64898 39.44647  27.72899  67.83102  75.59510   100  b 
#  Vapply 15.05799 16.62862 25.52292  17.57840  18.94187  64.09142   100 a  
#    Dist 62.25154 66.00407 95.46239 104.26654 107.21883 150.30602   100   c
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I will accept as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: Could also use `as.matrix(dist(x))` in place of the `abs(outer(...))`. I imagine it makes about half as many calculations.

Comment: @Frank I was thinking that but I always thought that `outer` is much faster than `dist`. I think you even once posted a question regarding that, no? Though it could save some time on `abs`. dunno.

Comment: Sounds familiar, yeah. It *shouldn't* be slower, anyway, but I don't know its internals or remember the timings.

Comment: Using `dist` requires some tweaking; it yields a lower diagonal matrix (without the diagonal), so the row number is not the actual index number.

Comment: @RHertel Tweaking like `as.matrix`?

Comment: @Frank No, what I mean is that `which(as.matrix(dist(test_vector)<20),arr.ind = TRUE)` yields `(5,1)` instead of the correct pair `(6,1)`

Comment: If you are benchmarking, `vapply` might be better. ie. `vapply(x, '-', ...=x, numeric(6))`

Comment: @akrun was just adding it

Comment: @RHertel I am suggesting a particular replacement in the comment above, which does not lead to your code, but rather `which(rowSums(as.matrix(dist(x)) < 20) > 1)` You are missing the `>1` part present in all David's now numerous variations above :)

Comment: @Frank I understand. You were suggesting to use both `dist` and `rowSums`. But it should be possible to get the result without using `rowSums`, by only checking the entries of the triangular `dist` matrix. Then, however, the aforementioned problem arises concerning the row numbers (which can be solved, but probably not in an elegant and compact way).

Comment: @RHertel Yeah, probably best to construct a matrix and then assign the result to it, since `as.matrix` doesn't make sense there. Alternately, you could do the arithmetic to go from `which(dist(x) < 20)` to the correct arr indices.

Comment: @RHertel Added a way, below.

Answer (score 3):

Following a discussion with @RHertel:

```
w     = which(dist(x) < 20)
pairs = t(combn(length(x),2))

pairs[w, , drop = FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    6
```

This way, you can see which pairs of elements are within 20 units of each other. If you just want the list of element indices, that's `unique(c(pairs[w,]))`.